# append key if matches specific index and keyword?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
titleValues = {'Movie 1 (1998)': ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'Movie 2 (1994)': ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0']}

categories={'unknown': '0', 'Action': '1', 'Adventure': '2', 'Animation': '3', "Children's": '4', 'Comedy': '5', 'Crime': '6', 'Documentary': '7', 'Drama': '8', 'Fantasy': '9', 'Film-Noir': '10', 'Horror': '11', 'Musical': '12', 'Mystery': '13', 'Romance': '14', 'Sci-Fi': '15', 'Thriller': '16', 'War': '17', 'Western': '18'}

selectedCol = 1

titles=[]
for key, value in titleValues.items():
 for num in value:
  if num == '1':
   valIdx = value.index(num)
  if valIdx == selectedCol:
   titles.append(key)
  else: 
   continue
print(titles)
```

output:

```
   ['Movie 1 (1998)', 'Movie 1 (1998)', 'Movie 2 (1994)', 'Movie 2 (1994)', 'Movie 2 (1994)', 'Movie 2 (1994)']
```

I think it appears 6 times because of the six '1' occurrences. However, how can I only obtain two names as for both lists '1' appears at index 1.

```
['Movie 1 (1998)', 'Movie 2 (1994)']
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? only when titleValues contains a one, put key once in a list?

Comment: yep, if titleValues contains a one and its at also at only index 1, then put the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only when titleValues contains a one, put key once in a list:

```
titles = [k for k,v in zip(titleValues.keys(),titleValues.values()) if '1' in v]
```

result will be

```
print(titles)
# ['Movie 1 (1998)', 'Movie 2 (1994)']
```

---

Explanation

1. Create two iterables (keys, values)

```
print(titleValues.keys())
#dict_keys(['Movie 1 (1998)', 'Movie 2 (1994)'])
print(titleValues.values())
#dict_values([['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0']])
```

2. zip, is a function to iterate element-wise and simultanouesly over two iterables

```
print(list(zip(titleValues.keys(),titleValues.values())))
# [('Movie 1 (1998)', ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']), ('Movie 2 (1994)', ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'])]
```

3. in a for-comprehension you can access elements of both iterables (specified variable name: k for element in first iterable and v for element in second)

Comment: could you explain the zip function in this case?

Comment: yes will edit the answer, and add an explanation

Comment: no need for zip, but you have the point. You can add the second test too : 
```titles = [k for k, v in titleValues.items() if '1' in v and v.index('1') == selectedCol]```